# Adding cart costs more than two minutes to respond

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, performance

Magento version: CE 1.9.2.2
host: Synology DS 1515+ (DSM version: 5.2)

There are two websites, one of which has 364 products, the other has none.
Recently, it takes more than two minutes for adding cart to respond from server.
If I don't login as a customer, it respond very fast(when I'm a visitor).

I've enlarged memories of opcache.ini, PHP runtime, and Mariadb,
there is no improvement.

I've tried to clean manually /var/cache and /var/session,
it's become fast for a very short time(, then it recovers to respond slowly).

I traced with Firebug, finding out that there are totally three places responding very slowly(more than two minutes or longer):
/checkout/onepage/add
/checkout/onepage/saveBilling
/checkout/onepage/savePayment

Answer (score 1):

It's solved.

I find out there are many items to calculate total amounts when add cart and checkout.

What takes most time is Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping.

I enter into Admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods, and disable those not required, for example, UPS, FedEx.

I's done.